# Is the Konami code for Unikong inaccurate?

Tags: cheats, unikong

*Unikong* supports the Konami code entered as:
<kbd>↑</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

My own memory of entering the code was that the code was:
<kbd>↑</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-[<kbd>Select</kbd>+<kbd>Start</kbd>]

Was the classic Konami code just for *Contra* and then other games had a similarity or is my memory just that bad?

Comment: Select is only necessary if you're playing a 2-player game.

Comment: Note: Pressing enter actually isn't part of the code, but is nesscary to run it.

Comment: @RikerW, `enter` is part of the code ( in the Unikong version)  because pressing the play button with the mouse after entering the standard Konami code does not work. It is also is part of the `konamiArray` variable in the source code

Comment: @epicTCK but enter also just presses whatever button is highlighted.  I accidentally triggered it on the credits. :P

Comment: Thank you @Powerlord!  I've wondered for years why people never include the select when describing the code.  Finally makes sense.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## The Konami Code

[As stated on the Wikipedia page for the Konami Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) the code is:

> <kbd>↑</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.

Start is appended to the end of the code in the game Contra.
However, the "Konami Code" referenced in Unikong appends an enter to to the end.
Source: Unikong Source Code (Inspect Element)

## Using the Konami Code in Unikong

Upon pressing the keys corresponding to the Konami Code in the Unikong menu, the game will start with golden particles on the screen, playing the music labelled as "`gameOverTheme` and `gameOverIntro`" in the source code. The music could be described as a remix to [Rick Astley's "Never Gonna Give You Up"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: I have found my new-favorite song.

Comment: I could listen to it all day. We should  start a movement for the release of the song under public domain.

Comment: That's not a bad idea! We just need a small, robotic Rick Astley to sing. Then the song would be gold (badges).

Comment: I feel like this answer is a PPCG party... :P

Comment: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/unikong/game-over-music.mp3 is the original source file for the music. This is owned it's respective owner, not me, please don't sue.... :D @RikerW

Comment: @epicTCK It ain't ours to release as such, but... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277763/155160

Comment: Video not available in germany ggwp

Comment: Thank you @epicTCK!  I always considered the start was part of the code.  As @Powerlord points out, the select was required for 2-player games which explains that.

Comment: GRRR, I hate rickrolls.

Comment: It's not a rick roll if it's labeled  Rick Astley's "Never Gonna Give You Up"